# Give Dynamic URL in HTML audio Tag

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, audio

I am using audio tag in html along with angular js, In which I have to give the source  of the audio which I want to play as given below.

```
    <audio src="http://localhost/audio/221122/play/212223.mp3" 
    audio player controls 
    pre-load="none"></audio>
```

I just want to make this URL dynamic,in which 221122 and 212223 should some variable like folder Name and media File which can have any dynamic value.

Can anyone help me how this could be done? Do I have to write something in the controller?

THANKS.

Comment: Yes, in the controller you have to get a list of audio files ID's. Then you place those values in the `$scope.files = [value1, value2]`, then in the template you iterate over an `ng-repeat` to get your values like this `ng-repeat file in files ...... <audio src="http://localhost/audio/221122/play/{{file}}.mp3"`

Comment: this is an example for multiple files :)

Answer (score 0):

In your template:

```
<audio audio player controls 
    ng-src="http://localhost/audio/{{model.folderName}}/play/{{model.audioName}}"
    pre-load="none"></audio>
```

In your controller:

```
$scope.model = {
    folderName: '221122',
    audioName: '212223.mp3'
}
```

From the Angular [ngSrc directive](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc) docs:

"Using Angular markup like {{hash}} in a src attribute doesn't work right: The browser will fetch from the URL with the literal text {{hash}} until Angular replaces the expression inside {{hash}}. The ngSrc directive solves this problem."